# How to start with fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

### I am a beginner to study JS. Now I encounter an issue to start with `fabric.js` which needs your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>fabric_test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="512" height="512" style="background-color: rgb(222, 222, 222)">
        Your browser does not support canvas tag!
    </canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
        // create a rectangle object
        var rect = new fabric.Rect({
          left: 100,
          top: 100,
          fill: 'red',
          width: 20,
          height: 20
        });

        // "add" rectangle onto canvas
        canvas.add(rect);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

My question is:

1. Why the rectangle doesn't draw on canvas when i open the saved html file?
2. The fabric I download is a folder which contains several folders and files. I just copy the `all.js` file on current location. Is this right?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? ( To open the web developer tool in chrome, press f12. You will find a console tab there. )

Comment: yes, there are warning/errors there... I think i don't include all js files. <script type="text/javascript" src="all.js"></script>. Oops, how can i get start with fabric.js??

Comment: can you show the error here or on pastebin ? It better you start with a basic web development guide first.

Comment: Unexpected end of file while searching for color.   from DOM.  thanks your suggestion, iamkhush.

Comment: So who can give me a very simple demo to use fabric.js?

Comment: finally i know what happens. actually the rectangular has drawn on canvas but it covered since i set canvas's background. Changed the line to <canvas id="canvas" width="512" height="512">, you will see it.

Comment: what about the errors you saw on console

Comment: The errors was: "Unexpected end of file while searching for color. from DOM". Now it is okay, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused because you put a background in your canvas object. So, the color is over the inside elements. Remove the background style from your canvas.

Answer (score 0):

When you download the fabric zip file, on extraction you should find a folder fabric.js-1.4.4/dist copy the fabric.js file from there or the fabric.min.js file and include it instead of the all.js let me know if this works